# WebKit Mobile Browsers: Any difference between Android and iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, iframe, mobile-webkit, 3d-secure

I've got an issue that I'm trying to get to the bottom of and I can't seem to find an appropriate answer. Our mobile website - currently in test - uses a 3D Secure iframe.

Our tests have confirmed that where the iframe displays properly when using an Android phone (in-built webkit-based browser, Samsung Galaxy S II), it unfortunately does not for an iPhone (again, in-build webkit-based browser, Apple iPhone 4S). The iPhone simply does not display the iframe. I'm uncertain whether the iframe won't show or if it is merely positioned off-screen (but there are no CSS properties applied to either the iframe or parent that would affect its position/float/margins/padding).

Is there a major difference between two webkit-based browsers on different phones which would account for this? Has anyone suffered from the same issue? And if you can help, how do I try to solve it?

```
<iframe id="authenticationFrame" name="authenticationFrame" src="3d-secure-bit" height="400" width="330"></iframe>
```

Thanks,